# Is Physics being formally documented somewhere?

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations

Physics is an extremely diverse subject, with new phenomenon being mapped by the second. So, is it all being formally documented somewhere?

---

I'm specifically looking for a **centralized, formal knowledge-base**, from a legally certified institution. It would be absurd to expect *everything*, and so I won't. I would expect such a resource to contain classification, terminology, and overall a formal description of the standard model.

Comment: Do you read any science journals?

Comment: Yes, but how is that relevant?

Comment: Not science magazines, science journals

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: [Physical Review](https://journals.aps.org/archive/), [Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/current_issue.html), the list goes on

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: centralized, formal knowledge base... Does that mean one peer-reviewed database of all physics knowledge?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: Does that exist in computer science? Old English literature? Recipes for rhubarb pie? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne I assume it does exists for recipes of rhubarb pie. Apple pie, of course not. But rhubarb, yes probably.

Comment: @Jim: :-) The OP has a point, though. Most experimental data is lost. We have to trust the data analysis of the folks who did them because there is not a shred of useful evidence left of most of what we did. Even LEP data is now rotting on tapes that nobody will be able to read, I believe.

Comment: Actually, if there were a centralized database of physics knowledge of "immutable concepts", it would be a great resource for me and others who like to show where some such concepts are wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All physics knowledge does not exist on one centralized database. No matter how complete it is, there would always be some scrap of physics knowledge that exists on another database only. If there were a centralized database of all physics knowledge, I can assure you it would not be peer-reviewed. The peer review process is too lengthy for one database to do all of it for all of physics and the separate institutions that do peer reviewing don't generally want to give away the papers they review for free.

The closest thing to what you are describing is the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/). It is hosted by Cornell University and contains a massive database of non-peer reviewed material. Much of this material goes on to be peer-reviewed, but it usually isn't at the time of posting to arXiv. It is not a complete set of physics knowledge and I stand by my statement that it is not possible to have one centralized and complete database. But the arXiv is the best thing I can think of to suit your request.

Comment: Just as I had feared. In any case, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @VatsalManot: I'm kinda curious as to why you state, "Just as I had feared." here.

Comment: Right? I'd be more afraid if there was a database with every scrap of physics knowledge. How did they get that off my computer!? Are they watching me right now? And where would we store the zetabytes of experimental data?

Comment: @KyleKanos: I've been searching for a formal knowledge-base for a long time. StackExchange was my last hope.

Comment: When I say knowledge-base, I mean a compilation of what we generally consider to be 'immutable' concepts. I don't think experimental data should be included.

Comment: @VatsalManot: I don't think there's a formal knowledge base for *any* discipline. Especially so when there is *active* research going on that could *disprove* such "immutable concepts." I mean, to me at least, it doesn't really make sense to *expect* a complete repository of information since the information is not at all complete.

Comment: arXiv is good then. Nature and Physical Review are also good for immutable concepts

Comment: For a beginner, wikipedia is essentially a complete database

Comment: I suppose you could say that :/

Comment: The original 1960 film, "The Time Machine", had represented such an information database using spinning disks.  We should do that as obviously the books most would say is such a database (i.e. US Library of Congress) will ultimately rot on the shelves.  I often think of those spinning disks in that movie as a precursor to DVDs.  Of course, that was almost one million years into the future.

Comment: @K7PEH any electronic medium is even more volatile than books which as you say "rot on the shelves". Each new technology stores the bits of data with less and less energy, and additionally newer and newer interfaces are created, making old ones obsolete. As a result, even if the information on a century old electronic medium still survives, you'll have to literally _decrypt_ it since the specifications of the interface will most likely be lost by that time. Compared to that, the books are in human-readable format and much easier to read even if somewhat rotten.

Comment: @Ruslan -- Obviously you have never seen the 1960 movie "The Time Machine"!  My comment was written in jest.

Answer (score 1):

There would be a big difference between documenting the advance of truly fundamental physics, and documenting the advance of every investigation, discovery and idea which might count as physics.

The fundamental advances are documented in places like encyclopedias, textbooks, and the list of Nobel Prize winners. Perhaps the closest thing to a central, regularly updated repository of technical information about the state of fundamental physics  is http://pdg.lbl.gov, the website of the Particle Data Group.

A feature of recent decades in physics, which distinguishes them from the past, is the existence of a single equation that describes almost everything (I mean the Lagrangian of the standard model coupled to general relativity).

String theory is also immensely significant, as a framework which palpably has some chance of explaining both the unexplained assumptions which define the standard model, and the phenomena like dark matter which fall outside it. Here the hep-th archive at arxiv.org functions as the central repository of mathematical and conceptual progress in the subject. As in all areas of physics, review papers summarize the evolving state of research for newcomers, sometimes in an authoritative multi-author way, sometimes according to the opinions of a single author.